# Android RecyclerView CursorLoader for database in Assets

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursorloader

I am trying to implement `CursorLoader` that would connect to my SQLite db in `assets` folder, retrieve data and display with RecyclerView. I want to accomplish this with `CursorLoader`. I have seen many examples but most of them are using ListView or with RecyclerView they are using `ContentResolver` that would run CRUD operation.

I am looking for simple CursorLoader with RecyclerView that would **only** fetch data and display with RecyclerView.

Comment: @MikeM. and how would I write `something similar` to **only** query my database in `assets` folder?

Comment: How to do this with `CursorLoader`?

Comment: Thanks Mike for the hint. Yes I have a readonly database and I am now curious to see a working example with `AsyncTaskLoader`. :)